# every day or everyday what is the difference

Tags: grammar, adjectives

Is Everyday is a blessing or every day is a blessig, which one is correct? I think it is every day is a blessing, right?

Thx.

Comment: Duplicate: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/98039/i-play-tennis-everyday-or-i-play-tennis-every-day

Answer (score 2):

In the phrase **every day** the determiner "every" qualifies "day". The phrase describes the frequency of an event, for example

> Every day is a blessing.

The word **everyday** is an adjective meaning "commonplace", but not always *literally* every day, for example

> I dislike everyday jobs such as cleaning.

Comment: thx for your answer @Weather Vane. So which one do you prefer. **Every day** is a blessing or **Everyday** is a blessing?

Comment: Doesn't my answer make that clear? Which does it say?

Comment: Think it is every day

Comment: Yes, and it says **everyday** is an adjective.